# dhclient intercepting outbound packets

Tags: amazon-web-services, dhcp, nat

I have a service listening on a UDP port on an ubuntu machine on AWS. Another machine I have no control over is sending packets to this service, however the source port for these packets is set to 68. When my service wants to respond to these packets, it tries to send a UDP packet with destination port 68 back to the originating machine. For some reason these returning packets never reach their destination. In the syslog there is also a very suspicious log entry which reads:

```
Jan  9 15:17:08 ip-172-31-118-74 dhclient[1019]: Discarding packet with bogus hlen.
```

Which coincides with these packets being generated. Does that mean that somehow the local dhclient daemon is intercepting these packets?

It may be that the log entry is a red herring, but those packets still are not reaching their destination. This has worked in the past when a different source port was chosen, so this leads me to believe that the fact that 68 is being used is the reason I'm having trouble.

Some tcpdump output showing the incoming packets with source port set to 68.

```
10:38:04.892816 IP 1.1.1.1.68 > 172.31.118.74.500: BOOTP/DHCP, unknown (0x20), length 448
10:38:04.901687 IP 172.31.118.74.500 > 1.1.1.1.68: BOOTP/DHCP, unknown (0x20), length 481
10:38:08.893218 IP 1.1.1.1.68 > 172.31.118.74.500: BOOTP/DHCP, unknown (0x20), length 448
10:38:08.893835 IP 172.31.118.74.500 > 1.1.1.1.68: BOOTP/DHCP, unknown (0x20), length 481
10:38:16.093319 IP 1.1.1.1.68 > 172.31.118.74.500: BOOTP/DHCP, unknown (0x20), length 448
10:38:16.093908 IP 172.31.118.74.500 > 1.1.1.1.68: BOOTP/DHCP, unknown (0x20), length 481
10:38:24.901839 IP 172.31.118.74.500 > 1.1.1.1.68: BOOTP/DHCP, unknown (0xff) [|bootp]
```

(original public IP replaced with `1.1.1.1`) And the syslog output for the same time period

```
Jan 10 10:38:16 ip-172-31-118-74 dhclient[755]: Discarding packet with bogus hlen.
Jan 10 10:38:16 ip-172-31-118-74 dhclient[1019]: Discarding packet with bogus hlen.
```

Comment: It *seems* improbable that your machine's dhclient can even see packets you are sending out, regardless of the destination port.  It also seems odd for something that isn't a DHCP server to be sourcing packets from port 68.  Have you wiresharked the packets?  Is it possible that you're sourcing from port 68 and then getting another reply back, or some other permutation?

Comment: Yeah I would also have thought it improbable, but I can't find any information about that log entry anywhere so I thought it might be relevant. I've looked at the packet data using tcpdump, the incoming packets have the source port set to 68 when they reach the AWS machine. I'll add some of this output to my Q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the device is a Cisco router this could be a PAT issue is versions prior to 8.4. The ports are translated based on pools that are allocated

From the support forum link below:
The ASA and PIX divide up the PAT port allocation range into three pools:

1. 1-511
2. 512-1023
3. 1024-65535

I hope that helps.

https://supportforums.cisco.com/t5/security-documents/asa-how-the-asa-allocates-pat-translations-pre-version-8-4/ta-p/3116197